# Is it possible to distribute an Enterprise app via Testflight without the recipients having to create an account?

Tags: ios, testflight

I have an Enterprise app to distribute to a few hundred employees. I'm currently evaluating whether to use Testflight or not.

I want the process of installing the app to be as quick and easy as possible, however experimenting with Testflight it seems people have to create an account with Testflight first before they can install the app, which is an extra step I'd rather avoid.

Is there a way the user's can install the Enterprise app hosted on Testflight without first having to create an account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently no, we have intentionally avoided such functionality.  In the event that a tester decided to share the install link you would have an unauthenticated link sitting in the wild.

If you're concerned about the pain of inviting 100 people, the quickest way to get your employees into TestFlight would be using a recruitment URL (https://testflightapp.com/dashboard/team/recruitment/edit).

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to get people enrolled without an email having to be sent to the device?